# Github API Commit Comparison returns 404 when using 2 dot notation

Tags: github, github-api

When I use the [Github API Compare Commit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#compare-two-commits) endpoint, if I use the two dot notation to compare commit hashes it returns a 404 error.

```json
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits"
}
```

If I change the API request to be 3 dots with the exact same commit hashes, it works fine. If I use the [Github UI](https://github.com/github/docs/compare/b5938a09373f3d93f8af19209d42ef35240b9eb2..97d8746422f1ff44a21534ee1951429356311ac0) and use the two dot notation for the same hashes, the comparison loads fine. Same with three dot notation.

The repo is private, so I can't share it, but the commits are on the same branch and only 2 or 3 commits apart. I have also tried cross branch and that too didn't work in the API with two dots, but worked in the UI.

### Example of this issue using a public repo

Github API (Error): https://api.github.com/repos/github/docs/compare/b5938a09373f3d93f8af19209d42ef35240b9eb2..97d8746422f1ff44a21534ee1951429356311ac0
Github UI (Success): https://github.com/github/docs/compare/b5938a09373f3d93f8af19209d42ef35240b9eb2..97d8746422f1ff44a21534ee1951429356311ac0

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with 3 periods on private repos via the API

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for that endpoint it only supports a 3-dot notation.

> The base branch and head branch to compare. This parameter expects the format BASE...HEAD.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#compare-two-commits--parameters